# Firebase function says document doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am very new to Firebase functions. I wrote the following function which I expect to return a document by its ID. The document with that ID does exist. In the following code however, it always returns "Quiz not found". Am I doing something wrong?

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

exports.getQuizById = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    const quizId = request.query.id;

    if (!quizId) {
        response.status(400).send('Quiz ID is required');
        return;
    }

    try {
        const quizDoc = await getFirestore().collection('quizzes').doc(quizId).get();

        if (!quizDoc.exists) {
            response.status(404).send('Quiz not found. ID: ' + quizId);
            return;
        }

        response.status(200).json(quizDoc.data());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting quiz document:', error);
        response.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: How do we, the readers of your code, know for sure that the document exists?  I've never been mislead by the results of a `get()` - it's always been my mistake if that's not what I expected.  Please update the question to show the id of the document (log it in your function), and a screenshot or some other way to verify which document you see that exists in the "quizzes" collection.

Answer (score 0):

Updating just to be complete. Doug's comment above was mostly correct, it was user error. As a complete and total noob to Firebase functions, I was using the emulator to test my code. I was correct that the Quiz ID was correct and that it existed, however, that was on the LIVE server. I didn't realize the emulator ALSO had a tab where I was supposed to create the test data for the EMULATOR. I had assumed the emulator had made a copy of the live data already. That was my mistake.

Moral of this story - the emulator doesn't mimic YOUR server, it mimics A server. It is a blank emulator.

Comment: You can use the local emulator for Cloud Functions and also test against an actual cloud product Firestore.  You just have to pass the correct configuration to initializeApp (instead of passing nothing, which assumes that the function is deployed part of the same emulator or cloud project where it's running).

Comment: You can also un-accept the other answer so as not to mislead future readers that it's a viable solution to the problem.  Also consider maybe updating your question with the details of your test scenario to also help future readers understand how their situation might or might not be the same as yours.  The code you had was fine - it was only your expectations that needed correcting.